# How to remove value from array if it matches a value from another array?

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, I am running the following command `$AllU365Users = Get-MgUser -Filter 'assignedLicenses/$count eq 0' -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable unlicensedUserCount -All` to get a list of users who do not have an O365 license assigned to them and storing this in the variable $AllU365Users. Output of `$AllU365Users[0]` looks like this:

```
Id                                   DisplayName  Mail UserPrincipalName     UserType
--                                   -----------  ---- -----------------     --------
002b603e-4da8-4375-a9d9-d69a22a50ef9 WCSNCservice      WCSNCservice@test.com
```

I have another variable, $UnwantedUsers, that contains a list of names which correlates to the DisplayName of certain users in $AllU365Users that looks like this `$script:UnwantedUsers = "ABM User, WCSNCservice, Afaria Service Account, APC, etc`

What I would like to happen is that for all the unlicensed users stored in $AllU365Users that have a DisplayName that matches a value in $UnwantedUsers, remove/filter them out of $AllU365Users. Can store them in the same variable or a new one, say $FilteredUsers. I have tried using Where-Object to filter based on a different SO post I found by doing the following: `$FilteredUsers = $AllU365Users | ? ($_.DisplayName -notin $script:UnwantedUsers)` however this does not work and $FilteredUsers just comes up blank. I simply don't know enough PS to figure this out myself without an example to work off of.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. As currently written, `$script:UnwantedUsers` seems to be a _string_ (and not a list/array)…

Comment: You're most of the way there, but ```$script:UnwantedUsers``` is a single string - PowerShell doesn't know you want to compare the ```DisplayName``` to the individual comma-separated parts of the string - it just treats the whole string as a comparison value.  Try splitting it into an array like this:```$unwantedNames = $script:UnwantedUsers.Split(",").Trim();``` and then ```$wantedUsers = $AllU365Users | where-object { $_.DisplayName -notin $unwantedNames }```

Comment: oh my god that was it, i just didnt have that array set up correctly. 4 more eyes never hurts!